# Unity when game launched on Android it stretches based on aspect ratio

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-manifest

I have a problem, the game, when launched on any device looks stretched on all devices which have other than 16:9 aspect ratio. The game in 16:9 aspect ratio should look like this:
[16:9 editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3h5qi.png)
But on all other aspect ratios it is supposed to optimize the layout based on canvas scaler: 
[canvas scaler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkwNO.png)

So when I play in the editor on 18:9 aspect ratio, the game looks like this:
[18:9 editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wh8Xp.png)

BUT when I build and launch the game on my 18:9 phone, the layout isn't optimized based on the canvas scaler, but it stretches and looks like this:
[18:9 phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zd2lc.jpg)

I don't know where the problem is, probably in the player settings or in the manifest. Any help would be very appreciated. 
Here's my manifest:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" package="com.unity3d.player" android:installLocation="preferExternal" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
  <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
  <application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true" android:name="io.fabric.unity.android.FabricApplication">
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="android.max_aspect" android:value="2.5" />
    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-9607380768219031~4647670065"/>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: I dont thin this is because of manifest. And you cannot build just for specific dimensions. Thats why Unity's UI anchor is used for this type of situation. And how can you tell that 18:9 is for the 1080x1920?

Comment: I don't know what's the reason behind it, either (manifest was only a suggestion). But the problem isn't in the canvas, camera or anchors. I have built a lot of games with exact same settings and never encountered this issue. Of course, I use anchors, as you can see at the photos.